# how to host angular 2 website?

Tags: angular, server, hosting, frontend

How to host angular 2 website?

I am new to angular 2 and I made a simple website with no back-end.

I wondered that when I tried to open directly index.html file, it opens with error.

But after command `"npm start"` it works fine, which runs a local server on computer.

So, how to host this website on simple hosting sites (Not a Dedicated Server..!)?

I think hosting sites automatically find index.html file, but here is the problem, index.html is don't start without `"npm start"` command.

can I have to start an process for that on server?

please guide me.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html
Every HTTP server can serve an Angular2 application

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Host your Angular 2 App on **Firebase** using these simple steps:
Do Create a project with Angular CLI first. Get More info here https://cli.angular.io/

**Step 1: Build your App**

Run the below cmd to build

```
ng build --prod
```

**Step 2: Create FireBase project and Install Firebase CLI**

Open the Firebase console at https://console.firebase.google.com/ and create a new Firebase project.

To install the Firebase command line tools run:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

**Step 3: Deploy to FireBase**

Run the below firebase cmd to login:

```
firebase login
```

It will open the browser and ask you for authentication. Login with your Firebase account. There after you can close the browser window. On the command line you'll receive the message that the login has been performed successfully.

Now run the below cmd:

```
firebase init
```

First of all you're being asked which of the Firebase client features you want to use. You should select the option Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting site. Next the Firebase client will ask which folder to use for deployment. Type in **dist**. That is important because that is the location where our production build is stored.

Next the question is ask if this app is a single page app and if it should rewrite all URLs to index.html. In our case we need to answer yes.

Last question is if Firebase should over write file index.html. The answer to that question is no.

Now, Run the below cmd to deploy:

```
firebase deploy
```

Firebase will provide a **URL** which you can use to access your application online.

***[Update]***

Now after you have successfully deployed your app if you want to make some changes and deploy the code on same URL. Follow the same procedure. But make sure You are pointing to your project.

**To list all projects use this command:**

```
firebase list
```

**To make a project as a current project use:**

```
firebase use <project_id>
```

Comment: Hello i have followed this instruction and it was possible to upload my app ! .. But now i have one problem trying to update my app, bacuse i have made some changes... how can i update ?

Comment: Hi @IxamDeirf It is simple you have to follow the same steps but before that make sure your you are pointing to the current project that you are working on. I have updated My answer. Please have a look at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks @amanDeepSharma it working like charm !!. Very interesting and valuable information shared for the angular newbies.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **http-server** :

**http-server** is a simple, zero-configuration command-line http server. It is powerful enough for production usage, but it's simple and hackable enough to be used for testing, local development, and learning.

```
npm install http-server -g
```

build the project by:

```
ng build -app
```

then on project directory use:

```
http-server dist/ -p 3000 // -p is port
```

on browser http://localhost:3000 or http://your-ip:3000

Answer (score 2):

you can use heroku to deploy your solution :

https://www.heroku.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have got a simple hosting package, the answer is **You can't**.

A hosting package at a normal hosting provider does not offer this.

Either you need a 'special provider' like Google Firebase or you need to have your own (virtual) machine (at a hosting provider).