# Host Angular2 projects on 000webhost.com

Tags: angular, server

I want to host my Angular2 app using [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/), but it shows a blank page.

It works fine with usual web site structure (index.html / main.css / main.js / ect...) but not with Angular2 projects.

Currently I am registered for free web hosting.

Thanks in advance

P.S. 
In otherwise please suggest some other way of Angular2 web hosting

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: potentially duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573987/how-to-host-angular-2-website

Answer (score 0):

Run ng-build --prod, using angular-cli. This creates package with js and css ready to put into your server.

Comment: where can I find that package?

Comment: How did you build your project to this time?

Answer (score -2):

You will need an express server to render the application, this cannot be done with 000webhost, but it can be done with Amazon's EC2 container; which I believe has one year free. You can also use DigitalOcean or Google Cloud ($300 trial credit) as well.

Comment: You do not need Express to host an Angular app at all! The bundle is just .js, .css and .html files.

Comment: @Always_hungry some server providers won't properly serve index.html