# How do I host an angular 2 app on my website?

Tags: angular, hosting

I am aware that there is a similar question on stack overflow already (namely this one: [how to host angular 2 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573987/how-to-host-angular-2-website)) but this didn't really anser my question.

I have made my first app in Angular 2 and I now want to get it online. I already own (free) websites at Wix and Weebly. Would it be possible to host my app on one of those websites by simply putting all files in the same folder structure as they are in now (after running `ng build --prod`)?

Or do I have to use a proper program that uploads files to a server?

Or will none of this work and is it really as complicated as I now think it is?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the .htaccess files for the correct resolving of the URL. (If Wix has one or you have access to it). There is a possiblity that the URL you are trying to load does not point to the index.html of your Angular app. Search for .htaccess files for Angular and you might see the problem.

You are correct in your `ng build --prod` and then simply upload the content of your `dist`  folder to a `public_html` folder. You do not need any special type of program for that. You are just uploading a static website with a lot of Javascript.

Comment: Don't forget to check the 404 handling of the hoster that it will redirect them to your angular app, that means every unknown subpart beneath your angular app should be handled by your angular app or you will get webservers 404 page and leave the angular context.

Answer (score 0):

After run ng build --prod the result of compiled angular app will be javascript , html ,css ,image or fonts all of these required just static http server on the server side normaly you need to update url writer in case of iis as example ,nest change the route hash statege in both case you map need to update base url if you host the app on subdomain or base url not the root.

this is my configration for host angular app on github pages

```
 "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "baseHref": "https://malbarmawi.github.io/angular-lessons/"
            }
          }
        },
```

[source](https://github.com/malbarmawi/angular-lessons)

[Deploy an Angular Application to IIS](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7)